# Can we use MySql enterprise edition with Magento community edition?

Tags: magento-1.7, mysql

Does any one know that if we can use MySql enterprise edition with Magento community edition?

If yes, are there any benefits of using MySql enterprise instead of MySql community version?

Please suggest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use either of the MySQL products for your Magento installation. The MySQL version doesn't matter to Magento.

MySQL Enterprise contains more features which can be compared with the community edition via these links: https://www.mysql.com/products/ https://www.mysql.com/products/community/

However for Magento I'd highly recommend using another flavor of MySQL such as Percona as you'll see improved performance over standard MySQL. https://www.percona.com/software/percona-server/ps-5.6

Someone else has asked a question about the best MySQL alternative [Which MySQL Server provides a better performance for Magento](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/936/which-mysql-server-provides-a-better-performance-for-magento)

Comment: Have you ever used MySQL Enterprise yourself in any of the project?

Comment: @Muk I haven't personally used it, I wouldn't say the pricing associated with it would give a real benefit.

Comment: Given MySQL isn't really a bottleneck on smaller/low traffic sites, it isn't going to make a difference what you use. Stick to stock MySQL or use Percona's branch if you plan on using their tools (contrary to popular belief there's no real world performance difference between standard MySQL and Percona's MySQL)